# Getting an undefined error from a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to gather my components in one place and components works just fine by themselves and when I try to gather them like this. I have a postId object in params by the way.
PostInfo component:

```
render() {
    let postId = this.props.match.params.postId;
    let selectedPost = this.state.posts.find((postItem) => {
        return postItem.id === parseInt(postId);
    });

    if (selectedPost === undefined || selectedPost === null) {
        return <div/>;
    }
    return (
        <div}}>
            <Card title={selectedPost.title} }}>
                <p>{selectedPost.body}</p>
            </Card>
        </div>
    );
}
```

gathering place:

```
render() {
    let postId =this.props.match.params.postId;
      return (
          <div>
              <PostInfo key={postId}/>
          </div>
    )
```

I got this big error saying:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'postId' of undefined.

Comment: its because your params object doesnt have a postid in it. did you verify

Comment: `this.props.match.params.postId` vs `this.props.params.postId`?

Comment: Is the error message unclear? Do you know what it means?

Comment: it's look like you have too many curly braces, if that copy paste just fix it

Comment: Looks like you are using React Router, is this component passed directly to a `<Route>`?

Comment: Yes it passed directly to a <Route>